# Can VS2008 and IIS V6 be on different computers to host a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

`Visual Studio 20008` is installed on a different computer running from `Citrix` (possibly in a different subnet) which I can access.
I installed IIS V6 on my local machine (Windows 7 Pro). When I create a asp.net c# website in VS2008 it doesn't appear under my wwwroot nor does it host the webpage when run.

I get an: **Server Error in '/' Application, HTTP 404 error, resource cannot be found.**

In the past both have been on the same computer.
Does `VS2008` and `IIS V6` have to be on the same computer to host a website project?
Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS uses `localhost` to debug and run.
I'm not sure if you can change this in VS. As far the application goes to run under `IIS` on another computer it would have to have the files on the other computer.
May I suggest placing your project on the other computer and using [ftp](/questions/tagged/ftp) to update files and you would not have to use the `VS Debug` option, But any class files would require you to publish via FTP the whole site.

Comment: Yes but to Debug on to another computer i cant see that possible, the files would need to be on the other computer for the other computers "IIS" to run the application. And yes you can have "IIS" "localhost" as a different host, but in debug with VS is what sets "localhost".

Comment: You may host your application on any "iis" server, but to run from VS they need to be on the same computer.